# Python Bluetooth socket gives OSError

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth

I would like to use sockets in python 3.9 on Windows 10 to connect to a HC-05 module on an arduino and send/read some characters. However, using the following code, I get this error:

```
import socket
adapter_addr = '00:21:11:01:FA:1C'
port = 1  # Normal port for rfcomm?
buf_size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 
socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.bind((adapter_addr, port))
s.listen(1)
try:
    print('Listening for connection...')
    client, address = s.accept()
    print(f'Connected to {address}')

    while True:
        data = client.recv(buf_size)
        if data:
            print(data)
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Something went wrong: {e}')
    client.close()
    s.close()
```

```
line 30, in <module>
    s.bind((adapter_addr, port))
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

I've also tried using the PyBluez library, but it gives similar errors.
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem might be to do with the RFCOMM channel number (what you refer to as port).  I suggest you first read up on that say [here](https://www.btframework.com/rfcomm.htm#channel), because your code otherwise looks fine at least as far as listening.  The reason channel 1 is giving you those problems (and I had the same problem when testing your code) is there's probably already another service like say a virtual COM port using that channel number.  If you try some other numbers you should find it doesn't fail.  The [winsock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-bind) library Python uses in turn has a constant BT_PORT_ANY you can use to automatically assign it but Python doesn't seem to expose this.  Through trial and error it seems to be defined to -1.

Given you're using RFCOMM you might want to look at using the virtual serial ports Windows already makes for you (COMx).  Something like [pyserial](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/) for instance.  This would be a lot simpler, and you can avoid everything Bluetooth related as long as you can identify your clients' serial ports.